# Ubuntu can't turn off Legion back logo light

Tags: drivers, c

Is there a way to turn on/off the Legion Slim 7 Logo light on Ubuntu OS? It works by pressing Fn+l on windows; doesn't work on ubuntu.

The keyboard light works perfectly fine.It is just the logo light. Is it possible to code a driver to do so? If so, Where should I start?

Comment: Start at the maker of the machine and ask them if it can be done.